# Function in $H^1$, but not continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, sobolev-spaces, examples-counterexamples

By the Sobolev embedding theorem, if $\Omega$ is bounded, $H^s(\Omega)\subset C(\Omega)$ for $s>1$, in $\mathbb R^2$. Where I can find a counterexample (if one exists) for the case $s=1$? I mean a discontinuous function ($n=2$),  that belongs to $H^1$.

Comment: see also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746289/discontinuous-sobolev-function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $\Omega$ be the disk of radius $r<1$ centered at the origin. Define $u(x,y) = (-\log(x^2+y^2))^{1/3}$. Clearly, this is not a continuous function.

But on  every line not passing through the origin, this  function is Lipschitz, therefore absolutely continuous. It remains to check that its partial derivatives are in $L^2$. By the chain rule, 
$$u_x(x,y) = \frac13 (-\log(x^2+y^2))^{-2/3} (x^2+y^2)^{-1} (2x)$$
Since $|x|\le (x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$, it follows that 
$$|u_x(x,y)| \le (-\log(x^2+y^2))^{-2/3} (x^2+y^2)^{-1/2} $$
This function is square integrable, as one can see by integration in polar coordinates.  The same applies to $u_y$; indeed we can simply relabel $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @mkl314 Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: $|\nabla\,u|$ is not square integrable over the disk $D=\{x^2+y^2<r^2<1\}$ 
centered at the origin, since $$\int_{D}|\nabla\,u|^2dxdy=
\pi\int_0^r\frac{d\rho}{\rho\log{\frac{1}{\rho}}}
= -\pi\log{\Bigl(\log{\frac{1}{\rho}}\Bigr)}\Bigl|_0^r=+\infty $$.

Comment: May I know how should I find the weak derivative if the disc has radius larger than $1$? I don't know how to handle the non-differentiable point of $|x|^{\frac{1}{3}}$ at $x=0$.