# Discontinuous functions in Sobolev Spaces

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Can somebody provide some intuitive reasoning why in higher dimensions can functions in Sobolev spaces be discontinuous? It is clear in 1D why a discontinuous function cannot be in a Sobolev space (by working out), but how does that work out in higher dimensions. And, what kinds of discontinuities are allowable. Thanks, Sandy.

Comment: You might want to check https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/749002/function-in-h1-but-not-continuous