Is there a bounded discontinuous function in the Sobolev space $H^{1/2}(\mathbb{S}^1)$?
I want to know, whether there is an example of an bounded, discontinuous function in $H^{1/2}(\mathbb{S}^1)$.
For the general question for $W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, if $sp>n$ one can use the embedding theorems for getting a continuous representative, even if its not restricted to the case of an bounded function. In the other cases normally one would argue by some standard examples, which are unbouded. (see for example "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/749002/function-in-h1-but-not-continuous"). But here we are in the case $n=1$, $s=1/2$ and $p=2$ for $H^{1/2}(\mathbb{S}^1) = W^{1/2,2}(\mathbb{S}^1)$ and also require the function to be (essentially) bounded.

trace maps from $H^s$ to $H^{s-1/2}$ so you can reuse the 2D $H^1$ example

Why should the image under the trace of this counterexample also be discontinuous?

Take that counterexample as a prototype: shift the function such that the singularity sits on the boundary, sum countably many such functions, then the singularities are dense, you get an unbounded function on the boundary, then apply sinus function.

Its also fine to take an unbounded function $f \in H^{1/2}(\mathbb{S}^1, \mathbb{R})$ and simply take $\exp(if(x))$.
