# What element of $H^{1/2}$ is the delta function not defined on?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, dirac-delta

The delta function is well known to be in $H^s(\mathbb{R})$ for $s<-\frac{1}{2}$, but not in $H^{-\frac{1}{2}}(\mathbb{R})$. Given that $H^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ is the dual of $H^{\frac{1}{2}}$, there must be some $f\in H^{\frac{1}{2}}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $<\delta,f>$ is undefined, since otherwise $\delta$ would be in $H^{-\frac{1}{2}}(\mathbb{R})$ by definition.

I would like an example of such an $f$. I am under the possibly mistaken impression that elements of $H^{\frac{1}{2}}(\mathbb{R})$ have well-defined values at points by the trace theorem.

Comment: Have you checked continuity?

Comment: Oh. That would be it.

Comment: Should that first inequality be $s<-1/2$?

Comment: As far as I know, a function from $H^{1/2}(\mathbb R)$ can have a singularity. Can you give a pointer to your 'trace theorem'?

Comment: Ok, now I see two problems with my problem. 

The trace theorem states that for a suitably nice domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and certain values of $s$, $u\in H^s(\Omega)\implies u|_{\partial\Omega}\in H^{s-\frac{1}{2}}(\partial\Omega)$

Here's an example:

http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1996-124-02/S0002-9939-96-03132-2/S0002-9939-96-03132-2.pdf

I was thinking that the Trace theorem held when $s=\frac{1}{2}$. I think that was a mistake ($s$ must be bigger than $\frac{1}{2}$). And even if delta can be shown to be defined (which I think it can't), it would need to be bounded.

Comment: Yes, Jonas. I fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Being in $H^{1/2}(\mathbb{R})$ allows for singularities that are milder than logarithmic: such as $\log\log|x|$ near $0$ (cut off to create a function with compact support). Perhaps the best way to see this is to use the fact that $H^{1/2}(\mathbb{R})$ is the trace space of $H^1(\mathbb{R}_+^2)$, and to verify that $u(x,y)=\log\log \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is in $H^1$ near the origin. This is done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/746656).