# Find a weak differentiable function which is discontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives, continuity

I'm seeking a weak differentiable function $f \in W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ which is discontinuous.
I think every weak differentiable function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ is continuous by 
[Sobolev embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#Sobolev_embedding_theorem), so an example should exist at least in $\mathbb{R}^2$ if it does. Is my guess correct? If so, could anyone please show me an example?

Comment: $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, with $f(x) = \frac{1}{\|x\|^a}$ for $a<n+1$, see exmaple 3.7 here https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/ch3.pdf

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746289/discontinuous-sobolev-function

Answer (score 2):

You require an integrable function that is absolutely continuous on almost all lines parallel to the coordinate axes, whose partial derivatives are also integrable. Try $f(x) = \dfrac 1{\sqrt{|x|}}$ and $\Omega = B(0,1)$ in $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. On $\mathbb{R}$ you will have no such luck.
An example in higher dimensions is relatively easy:
Take $f(x) = |x|^s$ where $s > 1- n$. In fact you can take any $C^1$ function in higher dimensions (on bounded domain for integrability) and just make it discontinuous in one point. This function will still have a weak derivative that is bounded.