# Embedding of $H^1$ and $L^{\infty}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Is there any simple example or proof to show that $H^1$ fails to be embedded in $L^{\infty}$?, where, $H^1=W^{1,2}$ is a Sobolev space.

Comment: On what domain?

Comment: I would suggest you consider $u(x) := |x|^{-\alpha}$ on $B(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ for suitable $\alpha$ and $n$.

Answer (score 2):

So, in dimension $1$, the embedding $H^1(\mathbb{R}) ⊂ L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is true. In dimension $d≥ 3$ you can take $\varphi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and consider for example $f(x) = \varphi(x) \,|x|^{-1/4}$ (or replace $1/4$ by any $\varepsilon < d/2-1$).

But I think you are mainly interested in the case $d=2$. In this case, you can use the counterexamples from [Function in $H^1$, but not continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/749002/function-in-h1-but-not-continuous) or [Discontinuous Sobolev Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746289/discontinuous-sobolev-function)